# Undo minify js after running gulp --production

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

My question is, I want to minify my js from my laravel project i'm using elixir, I know that if I run gulp --production it will minify my js.

What I want to know is if i decide i need to edit my js, how can i unminify the js folder, is that even possible.

I haven't minified my js yet for fear that I might not be able to undo it.

At the moment all my js is being concatenated into one file called all.js , my understanding is that if i run gulp --production , then all the javascript in that file will now be minified, if that is true, then how do i unminify it when i want to trouble shoot or edit some javascript

Comment: You should use gulp to generate your production code only.  It should never overwrite anything.

Comment: it should output a minified file elsewhere, not destroy your original code